# Only show specific type on picking images

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

I have a function to pick specific image type. But my gallery is showing all types and give it less alpha to the unmatched types. My expected  result is that the gallery only shows the specific types.
My code:

```
val intent = Intent(
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
                Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT
            else Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
        ).apply {
            addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
            this.type = type
        }
```

The result:
[image]

The expected result most be that the explorer only shows the color one on the top and no one else on this folder.

Comment: The behavior of `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` is up to Google and device manufacturers.

Comment: Yeah that's a system file picker, and I don't think there's anything you can pass to influence its display behaviour. At a guess, they (currently) do it that way so that the app can specify the file types it will accept, but the user isn't confused about why some of their stuff isn't showing up at all

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
In  `intent.setType("*/*");`  //Means you will able to select all types of files
As per your requirements you will change Type Please find [link](http://androidsbs.blogspot.com/2014/01/intent-settypestring-type-how-to-set.html) for all types

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("*/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
```

Comment: Im already doing this. Type parameter set the specific string with values from that link in every need it case such gif, png or videos. I'm asking if there is a way to no just put it in only selected the current type but not showing at all the other side files.